# animação efeito onda em corda SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

estou  fazendo uma animaçnao SVG e para ficar completo, só está faltando a animação da corda

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #364254;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1445.0834 580.2761">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_150"
          data-name="Gradiente sem nome 150"
          x1="3.2814"
          y1="453.8773"
          x2="921.2548"
          y2="453.8773"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#f27075"
            stop-opacity="0"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5248"
            stop-color="#2d6cea"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5932"
            stop-color="#457dec"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.7376"
            stop-color="#82a8f3"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.9447"
            stop-color="#e4ecfc"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_16"
          data-name="Gradiente sem nome 16"
          x1="939.9244"
          y1="351.193"
          x2="1492.4711"
          y2="243.7888"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.1341"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
            stop-opacity="0.7621"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.4043"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
            stop-opacity="0.3478"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.6262"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
            stop-opacity="0.0928"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.7707"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
            stop-opacity="0"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <filter
          id="AI_Desfoquegaussiano_4"
          name="AI_Desfoquegaussiano_4"
        >
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" />
        </filter>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient"
          x1="1021.6008"
          y1="714.8803"
          x2="1021.6008"
          y2="491.971"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#b9b9bd"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5039"
            stop-color="#fee7d5"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-2"
          x1="1015.1188"
          y1="715.6549"
          x2="1015.1188"
          y2="662.471"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#401737"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#2d6cea"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-3"
          x1="1020.4081"
          y1="701.4192"
          x2="1020.4081"
          y2="673.7128"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-4"
          x1="1042.4303"
          y1="595.163"
          x2="1042.4303"
          y2="578.9113"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-5"
          x1="1010.7335"
          y1="660.0198"
          x2="1010.7335"
          y2="649.7516"
          gradientTransform="translate(1576.9212 -408.0767) rotate(85.1016)"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-6"
          x1="939.1844"
          y1="408.3795"
          x2="939.1844"
          y2="315.0461"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.1808"
            stop-color="#7b7c84"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.3611"
            stop-color="#c1b6b0"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.4899"
            stop-color="#edd9cb"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5551"
            stop-color="#fee7d5"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.765"
            stop-color="#fef1e6"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-7"
          x1="902.9354"
          y1="401.3201"
          x2="954.2108"
          y2="401.3201"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13"
          data-name="Gradiente sem nome 13"
          x1="1116.3619"
          y1="414.6718"
          x2="1116.3619"
          y2="380.2045"
          gradientTransform="matrix(-0.9977, -0.0673, -0.0673, 0.9977, 2069.0162, 74.1349)"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#fee7d5"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#ffc5a9"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13-2"
          x1="205.2625"
          y1="396.867"
          x2="214.9458"
          y2="396.867"
          gradientTransform="matrix(0.992, 0.126, -0.126, 0.992, 801.135, -44.0006)"
          xlink:href="#Gradiente_sem_nome_13"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13-3"
          x1="1131.8728"
          y1="395.588"
          x2="1141.556"
          y2="395.588"
          gradientTransform="matrix(-0.992, -0.126, -0.126, 0.992, 2090.6347, 119.7773)"
          xlink:href="#Gradiente_sem_nome_13"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-8"
          x1="885.4584"
          y1="359.9616"
          x2="950.5125"
          y2="348.4908"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-9"
          x1="899.0038"
          y1="360.5009"
          x2="980.0221"
          y2="360.5009"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#f27075"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5248"
            stop-color="#2d6cea"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5932"
            stop-color="#457dec"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.7376"
            stop-color="#82a8f3"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.9447"
            stop-color="#e4ecfc"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-10"
          x1="901.7687"
          y1="404.3587"
          x2="955.1403"
          y2="404.3587"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-11"
          x1="855.3938"
          y1="472.4557"
          x2="988.2765"
          y2="449.0249"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-12"
          x1="957.1854"
          y1="420.1377"
          x2="966.852"
          y2="420.1377"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-13"
          x1="911.3371"
          y1="400.3877"
          x2="948.8464"
          y2="400.3877"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-14"
          x1="890.8894"
          y1="434.7924"
          x2="902.9896"
          y2="434.7924"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-15"
          x1="864.5134"
          y1="493.2369"
          x2="864.5134"
          y2="480.9984"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-16"
          x1="936.2392"
          y1="458.2563"
          x2="949.047"
          y2="458.2563"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-17"
          x1="880.6081"
          y1="418.679"
          x2="892.6152"
          y2="418.679"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-18"
          x1="896.9408"
          y1="366.1418"
          x2="896.9408"
          y2="351.4266"
          gradientTransform="translate(1018.2501 -599.6067) rotate(75.4121)"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-19"
          x1="928.1403"
          y1="464.5368"
          x2="952.6186"
          y2="464.5368"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-20"
          x1="957.7139"
          y1="347.5472"
          x2="816.6332"
          y2="103.1882"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#4eca7a"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.047"
            stop-color="#4dc278"
            stop-opacity="0.939"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.3699"
            stop-color="#438c69"
            stop-opacity="0.5406"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.6354"
            stop-color="#3c645d"
            stop-opacity="0.2487"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.8302"
            stop-color="#384b57"
            stop-opacity="0.0684"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.9336"
            stop-color="#364254"
            stop-opacity="0"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-21"
          x1="952.9233"
          y1="454.2961"
          x2="1034.4804"
          y2="454.2961"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#401737"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.076"
            stop-color="#433e45"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.2046"
            stop-color="#487a5c"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.3143"
            stop-color="#4ba56c"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.3994"
            stop-color="#4dc076"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.4494"
            stop-color="#4eca7a"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_8"
          data-name="Gradiente sem nome 8"
          x1="919.4737"
          y1="344.12"
          x2="1010.7447"
          y2="344.12"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#401737"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.1108"
            stop-color="#411e3a"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.277"
            stop-color="#423341"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.4782"
            stop-color="#45554e"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.7066"
            stop-color="#488360"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.955"
            stop-color="#4dbe76"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#4eca7a"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-22"
          x1="997.7087"
          y1="458.4906"
          x2="997.7087"
          y2="452.282"
          gradientTransform="translate(1142.391 -631.7504) rotate(73.0472)"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-23"
          x1="941.5251"
          y1="595.9957"
          x2="1022.4679"
          y2="499.5318"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-24"
          x1="988.6073"
          y1="623.721"
          x2="988.6073"
          y2="606.0954"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-25"
          x1="991.6126"
          y1="614.8744"
          x2="991.6126"
          y2="600.1377"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-26"
          x1="994.8687"
          y1="497.0958"
          x2="994.8687"
          y2="481.8919"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-27"
          x1="975.0767"
          y1="595.5689"
          x2="975.0767"
          y2="584.3129"
          gradientTransform="translate(1479.6015 -431.9493) rotate(85.1016)"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-28"
          x1="821.4987"
          y1="382.8428"
          x2="816.8826"
          y2="385.073"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
          <stop offset="1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-29"
          x1="821.8294"
          y1="381.4053"
          x2="828.1228"
          y2="381.4053"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-28"
        />
      </defs>
      <g style="isolation: isolate">
        <g id="corda">
          <path
            d="M10.1381,523.7887a129.9984,129.9984,0,0,1,23.4478-28.0481,137.2,137.2,0,0,1,14.4833-11.4312,131.4185,131.4185,0,0,1,16.0282-9.3232A122.8008,122.8008,0,0,1,81.43,468.0534c2.9868-.9311,6.0182-1.7484,9.0912-2.4311q4.6143-.999,9.3441-1.5545a84.3237,84.3237,0,0,1,19.1751-.1527,64.1678,64.1678,0,0,1,19.0137,5.03,54.4889,54.4889,0,0,1,8.8048,4.9313,51.29,51.29,0,0,1,7.7448,6.6289,50.2482,50.2482,0,0,1,3.3489,3.8652l1.3657,1.7187c.416.5431.8833,1.0634,1.3227,1.5959,1.8007,2.11,3.7375,4.1481,5.7635,6.1129a126.0336,126.0336,0,0,0,27.638,19.9649A122.0777,122.0777,0,0,0,225.73,525.7655a88.8416,88.8416,0,0,0,32.9611,1.2545,76.21,76.21,0,0,0,7.9761-1.7469,72.5878,72.5878,0,0,0,7.7339-2.557,77.53,77.53,0,0,0,14.45-7.5716,100.2369,100.2369,0,0,0,23.87-23.0338,141.4885,141.4885,0,0,0,9.3889-14.208c1.4575-2.4627,2.7775-4.9956,4.1448-7.5432,1.4553-2.7422,2.9114-5.4836,4.4589-8.1762q4.6074-8.0952,9.8-15.8476,5.2212-7.7251,11.0333-15.0424A213.69,213.69,0,0,1,377.2119,404.11a180.8723,180.8723,0,0,1,30.526-22.0113,139.9645,139.9645,0,0,1,35.2769-14.33,104.4177,104.4177,0,0,1,38.5771-2.51,92.4736,92.4736,0,0,1,36.7547,12.78,110.5846,110.5846,0,0,1,28.7541,25.4918,144.872,144.872,0,0,1,10.9053,15.5219c1.6008,2.7056,3.2016,5.4117,4.6519,8.1864l1.113,2.0693,1.0443,2.0983,2.05,4.1369a222.2631,222.2631,0,0,0,17.4,30.2127,121.9379,121.9379,0,0,0,22.8687,25.18c8.7006,6.9742,18.6615,12.1735,29.2445,13.9654a50.7067,50.7067,0,0,0,15.9747.2238,56.6979,56.6979,0,0,0,15.497-4.6532,78.1028,78.1028,0,0,0,26.11-20.4673,99.4568,99.4568,0,0,0,9.81-13.8993c1.4532-2.45,2.7643-4.9855,4.01-7.5516l1.8876-4.0331c.6459-1.3956,1.3241-2.7754,1.9944-4.1585A228.387,228.387,0,0,1,730.51,418.6864a166.08,166.08,0,0,1,24.5238-27.74,121.2878,121.2878,0,0,1,14.8163-11.38,96.6508,96.6508,0,0,1,16.6384-8.7412,80.1964,80.1964,0,0,1,37.0089-5.8268c12.5584,1,24.5831,5.0685,35.5046,10.7034a148.2251,148.2251,0,0,1,30.0062,20.9443,250.8421,250.8421,0,0,1,25.2756,26.0567,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-2.2388,1.9964l-.0118-.0127a247.1063,247.1063,0,0,0-25.9278-24.6038,149.2618,149.2618,0,0,0-29.6935-19.15c-10.57-5.0008-21.9084-8.3606-33.3851-8.8706a72.891,72.891,0,0,0-33.3863,6.2489,88.3078,88.3078,0,0,0-14.9883,8.4326,112.4246,112.4246,0,0,0-13.4363,10.9474A144.7821,144.7821,0,0,0,749.3,410.4347a174.8567,174.8567,0,0,0-10.548,14.0031A217.9769,217.9769,0,0,0,721.4548,455.05c-.61,1.3342-1.2277,2.6648-1.8134,4.009l-1.8452,4.1693c-1.3191,2.8651-2.7168,5.6987-4.2729,8.45a110.8506,110.8506,0,0,1-10.6422,15.7293,88.3839,88.3839,0,0,1-29.8157,24.1271,69.0633,69.0633,0,0,1-18.8281,5.937,64.6783,64.6783,0,0,1-29.6086-2.2692,70.4885,70.4885,0,0,1-9.1971-3.605,88.2479,88.2479,0,0,1-16.52-10.25,135.2446,135.2446,0,0,1-25.883-27.606A225.59,225.59,0,0,1,554.0734,441.79l-1.9915-3.9177-.9819-1.9264-1.0427-1.8875c-1.358-2.5383-2.8467-4.9868-4.3273-7.4382a130.3666,130.3666,0,0,0-9.9445-13.85,95.8119,95.8119,0,0,0-25.1086-21.86,77.3089,77.3089,0,0,0-30.941-10.4064,85.0584,85.0584,0,0,0-16.4912-.2871,102.278,102.278,0,0,0-16.4418,2.7483,124.3046,124.3046,0,0,0-31.251,12.85,165.08,165.08,0,0,0-27.766,20.183,197.75,197.75,0,0,0-23.6736,25.2571q-5.3815,6.8186-10.2329,14.0516-4.8208,7.2434-9.1024,14.8357c-1.4388,2.5216-2.7905,5.0918-4.1444,7.66-1.4657,2.75-2.9455,5.5342-4.5528,8.2408a157.572,157.572,0,0,1-10.5269,15.8081,112.9818,112.9818,0,0,1-27.968,26.5646,93.3378,93.3378,0,0,1-17.5092,8.9514,89.2817,89.2817,0,0,1-19.0534,4.9525,102.9441,102.9441,0,0,1-38.6288-2.0733,134.4123,134.4123,0,0,1-35.1971-14.2581,139.3158,139.3158,0,0,1-29.8981-23.1059c-2.2146-2.29-4.3481-4.68-6.3677-7.2067-.4977-.6411-1.0125-1.2589-1.4918-1.9224l-1.3794-1.8546a37.9246,37.9246,0,0,0-2.4531-3.024,42.1378,42.1378,0,0,0-12.4763-9.4316c-9.5687-4.7971-21.0189-6.2548-32.3023-5.4208a107.2722,107.2722,0,0,0-33.3739,8.3137,134.2376,134.2376,0,0,0-30.1162,17.8426,136.8208,136.8208,0,0,0-24.7194,25.2979,1.5014,1.5014,0,0,1-2.48-1.6879Z"
            transform="translate(-9.9166 -135.4679)"
            fill="url(#Gradiente_sem_nome_150)"
          />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

código completo do SVG abaixo

https://codepen.io/yung-silva/pen/OKGjpJ

eu preciso que seja uma animação suave com efeito de onda, mas não consegui achar nada que me ajudasse

aqui está referencias mais próximas que conseguir encontrar

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/742876/screenshots/3631385/moon-walk.gif

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/123785/screenshots/3789858/spaceman_final.gif

https://media1.giphy.com/media/8lNaZuf2ZmF54oalhP/giphy.gif

alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: você já tem alguma ideia de como vai fazer isso?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo não, nenhuma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para não ficar muito complexo, tendo que importar algumas bibliotecas tipo GSAP para "morfar" o `path` da corda no SVG, vc pode usar algumas propriedades de `transform` do CSS para fazer essa animação de forma particular na corda.

Ela ficaria assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como no Snippet do stackoverflow não cabe o código todo vou deixar o código só da corda. E aqui tem um link pro SVG completo como na imagem https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/XWrppgB

Vc pode brincar com todos esses valores de `transform` para deixar mais ao seu gosto.

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    background: #364254;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

svg {
  animation: mover 4s infinite;
  /* perspective: 800px; */
}
#corda {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: moverCorda 4s infinite;
}


@keyframes moverCorda {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(1) rotateY(0deg) rotate(0deg);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translateX(10px) scaleX(1.05) rotateX(45deg) rotate(10deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(1) rotateY(0deg) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1445.0834 580.2761">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="Gradiente_sem_nome_150" data-name="Gradiente sem nome 150" x1="3.2814" y1="453.8773" x2="921.2548" y2="453.8773" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f27075" stop-opacity="0" />
                <stop offset="0.5248" stop-color="#2d6cea" />
                <stop offset="0.5932" stop-color="#457dec" />
                <stop offset="0.7376" stop-color="#82a8f3" />
                <stop offset="0.9447" stop-color="#e4ecfc" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="Gradiente_sem_nome_16" data-name="Gradiente sem nome 16" x1="939.9244" y1="351.193" x2="1492.4711" y2="243.7888" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#2d3d54" />
                <stop offset="0.1341" stop-color="#2d3d54" stop-opacity="0.7621" />
                <stop offset="0.4043" stop-color="#2d3d54" stop-opacity="0.3478" />
                <stop offset="0.6262" stop-color="#2d3d54" stop-opacity="0.0928" />
                <stop offset="0.7707" stop-color="#2d3d54" stop-opacity="0" />
            </linearGradient>
            <filter id="AI_Desfoquegaussiano_4" name="AI_Desfoquegaussiano_4">
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" />
            </filter>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="1021.6008" y1="714.8803" x2="1021.6008" y2="491.971" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#b9b9bd" />
                <stop offset="0.5039" stop-color="#fee7d5" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="1015.1188" y1="715.6549" x2="1015.1188" y2="662.471" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#401737" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#2d6cea" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-3" x1="1020.4081" y1="701.4192" x2="1020.4081" y2="673.7128" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-4" x1="1042.4303" y1="595.163" x2="1042.4303" y2="578.9113" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-5" x1="1010.7335" y1="660.0198" x2="1010.7335" y2="649.7516" gradientTransform="translate(1576.9212 -408.0767) rotate(85.1016)" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-6" x1="939.1844" y1="408.3795" x2="939.1844" y2="315.0461" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#2d3d54" />
                <stop offset="0.1808" stop-color="#7b7c84" />
                <stop offset="0.3611" stop-color="#c1b6b0" />
                <stop offset="0.4899" stop-color="#edd9cb" />
                <stop offset="0.5551" stop-color="#fee7d5" />
                <stop offset="0.765" stop-color="#fef1e6" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-7" x1="902.9354" y1="401.3201" x2="954.2108" y2="401.3201" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13" data-name="Gradiente sem nome 13" x1="1116.3619" y1="414.6718" x2="1116.3619" y2="380.2045" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.9977, -0.0673, -0.0673, 0.9977, 2069.0162, 74.1349)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fee7d5" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ffc5a9" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13-2" x1="205.2625" y1="396.867" x2="214.9458" y2="396.867" gradientTransform="matrix(0.992, 0.126, -0.126, 0.992, 801.135, -44.0006)" xlink:href="#Gradiente_sem_nome_13" />
            <linearGradient id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13-3" x1="1131.8728" y1="395.588" x2="1141.556" y2="395.588" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.992, -0.126, -0.126, 0.992, 2090.6347, 119.7773)" xlink:href="#Gradiente_sem_nome_13" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-8" x1="885.4584" y1="359.9616" x2="950.5125" y2="348.4908" xlink:href="#linear-gradient" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-9" x1="899.0038" y1="360.5009" x2="980.0221" y2="360.5009" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f27075" />
                <stop offset="0.5248" stop-color="#2d6cea" />
                <stop offset="0.5932" stop-color="#457dec" />
                <stop offset="0.7376" stop-color="#82a8f3" />
                <stop offset="0.9447" stop-color="#e4ecfc" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-10" x1="901.7687" y1="404.3587" x2="955.1403" y2="404.3587" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-11" x1="855.3938" y1="472.4557" x2="988.2765" y2="449.0249" xlink:href="#linear-gradient" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-12" x1="957.1854" y1="420.1377" x2="966.852" y2="420.1377" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-13" x1="911.3371" y1="400.3877" x2="948.8464" y2="400.3877" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-14" x1="890.8894" y1="434.7924" x2="902.9896" y2="434.7924" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-15" x1="864.5134" y1="493.2369" x2="864.5134" y2="480.9984" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-16" x1="936.2392" y1="458.2563" x2="949.047" y2="458.2563" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-17" x1="880.6081" y1="418.679" x2="892.6152" y2="418.679" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-18" x1="896.9408" y1="366.1418" x2="896.9408" y2="351.4266" gradientTransform="translate(1018.2501 -599.6067) rotate(75.4121)" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-19" x1="928.1403" y1="464.5368" x2="952.6186" y2="464.5368" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-20" x1="957.7139" y1="347.5472" x2="816.6332" y2="103.1882" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#4eca7a" />
                <stop offset="0.047" stop-color="#4dc278" stop-opacity="0.939" />
                <stop offset="0.3699" stop-color="#438c69" stop-opacity="0.5406" />
                <stop offset="0.6354" stop-color="#3c645d" stop-opacity="0.2487" />
                <stop offset="0.8302" stop-color="#384b57" stop-opacity="0.0684" />
                <stop offset="0.9336" stop-color="#364254" stop-opacity="0" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-21" x1="952.9233" y1="454.2961" x2="1034.4804" y2="454.2961" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#401737" />
                <stop offset="0.076" stop-color="#433e45" />
                <stop offset="0.2046" stop-color="#487a5c" />
                <stop offset="0.3143" stop-color="#4ba56c" />
                <stop offset="0.3994" stop-color="#4dc076" />
                <stop offset="0.4494" stop-color="#4eca7a" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="Gradiente_sem_nome_8" data-name="Gradiente sem nome 8" x1="919.4737" y1="344.12" x2="1010.7447" y2="344.12" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#401737" />
                <stop offset="0.1108" stop-color="#411e3a" />
                <stop offset="0.277" stop-color="#423341" />
                <stop offset="0.4782" stop-color="#45554e" />
                <stop offset="0.7066" stop-color="#488360" />
                <stop offset="0.955" stop-color="#4dbe76" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#4eca7a" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-22" x1="997.7087" y1="458.4906" x2="997.7087" y2="452.282" gradientTransform="translate(1142.391 -631.7504) rotate(73.0472)" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-23" x1="941.5251" y1="595.9957" x2="1022.4679" y2="499.5318" xlink:href="#linear-gradient" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-24" x1="988.6073" y1="623.721" x2="988.6073" y2="606.0954" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-25" x1="991.6126" y1="614.8744" x2="991.6126" y2="600.1377" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-26" x1="994.8687" y1="497.0958" x2="994.8687" y2="481.8919" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-27" x1="975.0767" y1="595.5689" x2="975.0767" y2="584.3129" gradientTransform="translate(1479.6015 -431.9493) rotate(85.1016)" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2" />
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-28" x1="821.4987" y1="382.8428" x2="816.8826" y2="385.073" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
                <stop offset="1" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-29" x1="821.8294" y1="381.4053" x2="828.1228" y2="381.4053" xlink:href="#linear-gradient-28" />
        </defs>
        <g style="isolation: isolate">
            <g id="corda">
                <path d="M10.1381,523.7887a129.9984,129.9984,0,0,1,23.4478-28.0481,137.2,137.2,0,0,1,14.4833-11.4312,131.4185,131.4185,0,0,1,16.0282-9.3232A122.8008,122.8008,0,0,1,81.43,468.0534c2.9868-.9311,6.0182-1.7484,9.0912-2.4311q4.6143-.999,9.3441-1.5545a84.3237,84.3237,0,0,1,19.1751-.1527,64.1678,64.1678,0,0,1,19.0137,5.03,54.4889,54.4889,0,0,1,8.8048,4.9313,51.29,51.29,0,0,1,7.7448,6.6289,50.2482,50.2482,0,0,1,3.3489,3.8652l1.3657,1.7187c.416.5431.8833,1.0634,1.3227,1.5959,1.8007,2.11,3.7375,4.1481,5.7635,6.1129a126.0336,126.0336,0,0,0,27.638,19.9649A122.0777,122.0777,0,0,0,225.73,525.7655a88.8416,88.8416,0,0,0,32.9611,1.2545,76.21,76.21,0,0,0,7.9761-1.7469,72.5878,72.5878,0,0,0,7.7339-2.557,77.53,77.53,0,0,0,14.45-7.5716,100.2369,100.2369,0,0,0,23.87-23.0338,141.4885,141.4885,0,0,0,9.3889-14.208c1.4575-2.4627,2.7775-4.9956,4.1448-7.5432,1.4553-2.7422,2.9114-5.4836,4.4589-8.1762q4.6074-8.0952,9.8-15.8476,5.2212-7.7251,11.0333-15.0424A213.69,213.69,0,0,1,377.2119,404.11a180.8723,180.8723,0,0,1,30.526-22.0113,139.9645,139.9645,0,0,1,35.2769-14.33,104.4177,104.4177,0,0,1,38.5771-2.51,92.4736,92.4736,0,0,1,36.7547,12.78,110.5846,110.5846,0,0,1,28.7541,25.4918,144.872,144.872,0,0,1,10.9053,15.5219c1.6008,2.7056,3.2016,5.4117,4.6519,8.1864l1.113,2.0693,1.0443,2.0983,2.05,4.1369a222.2631,222.2631,0,0,0,17.4,30.2127,121.9379,121.9379,0,0,0,22.8687,25.18c8.7006,6.9742,18.6615,12.1735,29.2445,13.9654a50.7067,50.7067,0,0,0,15.9747.2238,56.6979,56.6979,0,0,0,15.497-4.6532,78.1028,78.1028,0,0,0,26.11-20.4673,99.4568,99.4568,0,0,0,9.81-13.8993c1.4532-2.45,2.7643-4.9855,4.01-7.5516l1.8876-4.0331c.6459-1.3956,1.3241-2.7754,1.9944-4.1585A228.387,228.387,0,0,1,730.51,418.6864a166.08,166.08,0,0,1,24.5238-27.74,121.2878,121.2878,0,0,1,14.8163-11.38,96.6508,96.6508,0,0,1,16.6384-8.7412,80.1964,80.1964,0,0,1,37.0089-5.8268c12.5584,1,24.5831,5.0685,35.5046,10.7034a148.2251,148.2251,0,0,1,30.0062,20.9443,250.8421,250.8421,0,0,1,25.2756,26.0567,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-2.2388,1.9964l-.0118-.0127a247.1063,247.1063,0,0,0-25.9278-24.6038,149.2618,149.2618,0,0,0-29.6935-19.15c-10.57-5.0008-21.9084-8.3606-33.3851-8.8706a72.891,72.891,0,0,0-33.3863,6.2489,88.3078,88.3078,0,0,0-14.9883,8.4326,112.4246,112.4246,0,0,0-13.4363,10.9474A144.7821,144.7821,0,0,0,749.3,410.4347a174.8567,174.8567,0,0,0-10.548,14.0031A217.9769,217.9769,0,0,0,721.4548,455.05c-.61,1.3342-1.2277,2.6648-1.8134,4.009l-1.8452,4.1693c-1.3191,2.8651-2.7168,5.6987-4.2729,8.45a110.8506,110.8506,0,0,1-10.6422,15.7293,88.3839,88.3839,0,0,1-29.8157,24.1271,69.0633,69.0633,0,0,1-18.8281,5.937,64.6783,64.6783,0,0,1-29.6086-2.2692,70.4885,70.4885,0,0,1-9.1971-3.605,88.2479,88.2479,0,0,1-16.52-10.25,135.2446,135.2446,0,0,1-25.883-27.606A225.59,225.59,0,0,1,554.0734,441.79l-1.9915-3.9177-.9819-1.9264-1.0427-1.8875c-1.358-2.5383-2.8467-4.9868-4.3273-7.4382a130.3666,130.3666,0,0,0-9.9445-13.85,95.8119,95.8119,0,0,0-25.1086-21.86,77.3089,77.3089,0,0,0-30.941-10.4064,85.0584,85.0584,0,0,0-16.4912-.2871,102.278,102.278,0,0,0-16.4418,2.7483,124.3046,124.3046,0,0,0-31.251,12.85,165.08,165.08,0,0,0-27.766,20.183,197.75,197.75,0,0,0-23.6736,25.2571q-5.3815,6.8186-10.2329,14.0516-4.8208,7.2434-9.1024,14.8357c-1.4388,2.5216-2.7905,5.0918-4.1444,7.66-1.4657,2.75-2.9455,5.5342-4.5528,8.2408a157.572,157.572,0,0,1-10.5269,15.8081,112.9818,112.9818,0,0,1-27.968,26.5646,93.3378,93.3378,0,0,1-17.5092,8.9514,89.2817,89.2817,0,0,1-19.0534,4.9525,102.9441,102.9441,0,0,1-38.6288-2.0733,134.4123,134.4123,0,0,1-35.1971-14.2581,139.3158,139.3158,0,0,1-29.8981-23.1059c-2.2146-2.29-4.3481-4.68-6.3677-7.2067-.4977-.6411-1.0125-1.2589-1.4918-1.9224l-1.3794-1.8546a37.9246,37.9246,0,0,0-2.4531-3.024,42.1378,42.1378,0,0,0-12.4763-9.4316c-9.5687-4.7971-21.0189-6.2548-32.3023-5.4208a107.2722,107.2722,0,0,0-33.3739,8.3137,134.2376,134.2376,0,0,0-30.1162,17.8426,136.8208,136.8208,0,0,0-24.7194,25.2979,1.5014,1.5014,0,0,1-2.48-1.6879Z" transform="translate(-9.9166 -135.4679)" fill="url(#Gradiente_sem_nome_150)" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```